# Replace null with zero in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query that could potentially return null values, in the event of this I want the query to return '0'. Here is the query

```
   SELECT (select count(goal) from fixtures where goal='1' and fixture='$fixture') as goalCountHome
from fixtures where fixture='$fixture'LIMIT 1
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `coalesce(column, 0)` will return the first non-null argument.

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry. I am using phpMyAdmin

Comment: which column  you want check  .. ??  goal?

Comment: @scaisEdge yes goal please

Comment: Use ISNULL() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: How can `goal` be null in your result set when you have a WHERE condition checking that `goal` is 1?

Comment: @scaisEdge basically if a goal has not been scored I want the count to return zero. At the minute the query is returning null which is then leading to undefined variable notice in my php. If the result is null I want it to return zero so I dont get this notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT (select count(goal) from fixtures where goal='1' and fixture='$fixture') as goalCountHome
FROM fixtures 
WHERE fixture = '$fixture'
LIMIT 1
```

**cannot** return `NULL` values.  The subquery is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`, so it always returns one row.  That row will contain a result from `COUNT()`.  `COUNT()` itself can never return a `NULL` value.  If there are no rows, then the value will be zero.

The outer query might return *no rows* but that is different from `NULL` values.

Of course, this query is way overcomplicated, and should simply be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as goalCountHome
FROM fixtures 
WHERE fixture = ? AND   -- pass this in as a parameter 
      goal = 1 ;        -- it looks like a number so I assume it is
```

Note that you should be passing parameters in using proper parameters rather than munging query strings.

Answer (score 2):

In MySql use IFNULL() function. For MsSql use ISNULL() function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySql, `IFNULL(<column_name>, 0)` should do.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  all the rows  and not the rows where goal is not null you could use count(*)

```
   select count(*) 
   from fixtures
   where goal=1
   and fixture='$fixture'
```

`count(goal)` return the number of rows  where goal is not null 
`count(*)` return  the total  number rows  selected

otherwise in general when you need not null values  in mysql you can ifnull(your_column, value) or coalesce(your_column, value)

based on you comment seems you need  sum(goal)

```
select sum(ifnull(goal,0))
from fixtures
where goal=1 
and fixture='$fixture'
```

Comment: basically if a goal has not been scored I want the count to return zero. At the minute the query is returning null which is then leading to undefined variable notice in my php. If the result is null I want it to return zero so I dont get this notice

Comment: I have updated the answer  because  could be that you are  looking for a conditional sum instead of a count

Comment: thanks for your help scaisedge. However this query returns null in the box instead of zero

Comment: answer  updated  using  1 instead of '1'  could be goal is a number

Comment: sum (ifnull(goal,0))
NULL

Comment: This is what is being returned

Comment: which data type is goal?  and are you sure that there are rows for  $fixture?